# System.Web.Helpers disappers when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have added System.Web.Helpers as a reference through NuGet Package Manager to my project and when I open it and start coding it work fine, no errors and I can use all the functions, the IntelliSense shows everything fine.

When I go to run/debug the code it appears to remove/forget the reference and I get the following 2 errors:

```
The type or namespace name 'Helpers' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

and

```
The name 'Crypto' does not exist in the current context
```

And until I save and re-open the project it doesn't recognise the reference is there.

If it helps the Solution and references are stored/saved on my local machine but Visual Studio is run from a remote apps server, (just in case it has something to do with where things are).

**Update** C# is not my first choice language and I am not a software developer full time so some of the more technical answer might need more explaining.

Kind regards

Matt

Comment: Is the dll in the output directory? did you check the 'AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select(e => e.FullName)' contains the WebHelpers assembly? (execute the select BEFORE you use any of the System.Web.Helpers methods/Types)

Comment: I'm going to outright admit that all of your comment is basically gibberish to me.

Comment: Oh well this would absolutely out of bounds for stackoverflow. I Created a chat for this discussion:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170096/system-web-helpers-disappers-when-debugging

Answer (score 0):

After some further research it appears that I needed to change the Target Framework from ".net Framework 4 Client Profile" to ".net Framework 4".